# Difference between DNA and Genome

Tags: molecular-biology

Can we safely use the terms `DNA` and `Genome` interchangeably or is there any (even slight) difference between the two?

Comment: note that epigenetic aspects are essential to body plan embryo morphology yet are not considered part of the Genome, due in part to current limitations of DNA sequencing

Comment: @ScottStensland I learnt the meaning of your comment now after attending Epigenetics course. Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oversimplifying:

- DNA is a specific form of molecule (desoxyribonucleic acid).
- Genome is the *information* of a specific organism stored on its DNA. (Not just his genes, i.e. the information in the coding parts of his chromosomes, but the whole of it.)

With just a little bit of scientific handwaving, you could conceivably synthesise DNA molecules that are just random sequences of ATCG. It wouldn't be the genome of anything.

Comment: I'd add that retroviruses have a genome not encoded by DNA, but RNA; and PCR primers are DNA not encoding a genome.

Answer (score 2):

DNA is any piece of DNA. Genome is a very specific piece (or pieces) of DNA: all of the DNA contained inside one cell, or organelle, or virus particle, from a specific species.

For a species with a single chromosome, like the bacterium, *E. coli*, then the bacterial genome is equivalent to the cell's chromosome. Same for a virus. For a metazoan, like *C. elegans*, which has six chromosomes, the nuclear genome is one copy of all the chromosomes and the mitochondrial genome is one copy of the mitochondrial chromosome.

So DNA is a general term, while genome is a specific term that can be used most clearly with a modifier to specify the species you are referring to (e.g., the human genome, or the duckbill platypus genome, etc.).